# showing the group is abelian

Tags: group-theory

I need someone to guide me to solve the following problem

> Let $a, b \in G$.
>   a. f $(a *b)^i = a^i * b^i$ for three consecutive natural numbers, then show that $G$ is Abelian.
>   b. If the above property holds only for two numbers, then it is not necessarily Abelian.

Comment: What do you mean by three consecutive integers?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar sorry, should have mentioned for natural numbers. $i, i+1, i+2$

Comment: $$(a*b)^i=a*b*a*b*a*b\cdots*a*b=a*a*a**\cdots*a*b*b*b\cdots*b*b$$Can you see it now?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi yes that is the question also from the same book except that I added the another following problem.